# REQUEST_METHOD default

Tags: php, get, default

Is
`$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` set to 'GET' by default?

This code

```
<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]; ?>
```

outputs 'GET' even if it is in an empty file with no other tags (`<html>` / `<form>` / `<?php ?>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the request sent by browser is always `GET`. Take a look [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3)

Look at this:

> 17.3 The FORM element
>
> ```
> <!ELEMENT FORM - - (%block;|SCRIPT)+ -(FORM) -- interactive form -->
> <!ATTLIST FORM
>   %attrs;                              -- %coreattrs, %i18n, %events --
>   action      %URI;          #REQUIRED -- server-side form handler --
>   method      (GET|POST)     GET       -- HTTP method used to submit the form--
>   enctype     %ContentType;  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
>   accept      %ContentTypes; #IMPLIED  -- list of MIME types for file upload --
>   name        CDATA          #IMPLIED  -- name of form for scripting --
>   onsubmit    %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- the form was submitted --
>   onreset     %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- the form was reset --
>   accept-charset %Charsets;  #IMPLIED  -- list of supported charsets --
>   >
> ```